# fatal: pathspec 'https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git' did not match any files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a relatively complex git statement which reads as:

```
git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ add https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git -A && git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ commit  https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git -m "update 20170707"
```

Which yields the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git' did not match any files
```

Now, if I locally cd to that path & `git status` I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   data_1.p

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So, it is a git repo.

Now, if I run:

```
git commit data_1.p -m "update"
```

I get:

```
[master 377c61b] update
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

and `git push` yields:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git
   74ad924..377c61b  master -> master
```

Yet, if I simplify my git command and run:

```
git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ commit  https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git -m " 20170707"
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec 'https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Could anyone help to diagnose what exactly I am doing wrong here?

I am providing username and password because this is distributed code.

Comment: Please provide comments if you are going to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to give the remote repository URL in each command.

[`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) command only accepts pathspec as parameter, so your command is trying to add a file `https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git`, which does not exists!

Just remove the URL from you commands:

```
git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ add -A
git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ commit -m "update 20170707"

# Then simply publish
git -C /Users/user_name/s/f/f_start/ push
```

The only git commands to set/change remote repository URL is [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote origin --set-url https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/my_repo.git
git remote -v
```